# How can I remove the first line from a csv file?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I'm trying to remove the first line of a csv file but I can't. This csv file is created dynamic and the columns change from time to time. What I want is to generate another file from this header and remove from actual. Example:

Before - csv file:

```
Laboratorio,Producto,
3M CHILE,3M,
3M CHILE,3M,
```

After - Csv_Header_File.csv:

```
Laboratorio,Producto,
```

Csv_Content_File.csv:

```
3M CHILE,3M,
3M CHILE,3M,
```

I've tried using filter and rownum variable but no success.

[image]


pdi-9.0.0.0

Comment: If you have row number, filter step should work. I think there have something else you need. Can you please share your sample transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have prepared a [solution](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SEY0i6oK8elBbbuOTIN3epZNv4bHm3WR?usp=sharing) for you, which will split your main csv file with 2 different csv file (One will contain only header and another will contain all values without header).

[image]

**In Addition**, If your column name are dynamic in your CSV input file then you can use this [SOLUTION](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14X01QP2dROEqUDQLymkfRF_Tbf3AQ5qq?usp=sharing). You just need to insert value in 'Data grid' step as much as you need total csv column. Here, i have added 20 column .

[image]

**Another alternate**, as your column name and amount of column are dynamic. You can use this [SOLUTION](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14G6Jy4lFFgsS39NNtDnXSRMW2vRAvXrB?usp=sharing). Here at first I calculate the number of column i have in my input csv file then go further as it is like my second solution.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but my problem is that the columns are dynamic. I can't pass A1, A2, etc.

Comment: I have added another solution. where you don't need to specify any column name. you just need to specify maximum amount of column name.

Comment: But how I will insert the maximum amount of columns if I don't know how many are gonna be?

Comment: For CSV input/output , we must need to define column /field. Thus, you need to specify the expected maximum amount of column . Suppose for microsoft excel 2007-2010, it support maximum column 16384. So I can say you can set maximum column for you will be 16384.

Comment: I think i can not make fulfill your expectation. I have added another solution. Where you don't need to care about your number of column of input CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

In "CSV Input" enable field Row Number. And after "CSV Input" add component "Filter rows" with condition "Row_Number_field" = 1, and skip this row

Comment: The problem is that number one is the first line in the content. not the title.